# How do you guide a character into discovering a world?

Tags: characters, dialogue

I'm writing a story about a creature that takes the shape of a human and travels seeing the world. This character has no clue about this new reality, as he had no body before this incarnation, and it needs a guide to teach him.

How should a guide be written so that it doesn't pull from the character, but follows and gives him a guidance.

Comment: Hello Luiso and welcome to SE. I tried to edit your question a bit to fix the grammar, but it is still a bit vague and unclear. Can you specify a bit more what you need, and give more details? It is too broad.

Comment: So, like the little fairy that helps the protagonist Link for example in The Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time? Little, unable to really do something, but knows a lot about everything, while the character is thrown into a reality that is very different from what he knew until the moment the story began?

Comment: @Secespitus i thought of something like that, a motherly guide that follows, i want to orientate the story in a discovery of a brand new world full of experiences to live from a candid and almost like a "neophite" to the world, its a concept i want to explore and try to build arround it

Comment: If you want to explore this concept then why would you want us to answer this question? I may not understand the question correct, but it looks like you are basically asking us to write that guide for you and at the same time your comment suggests that you want to write that yourself. "How should [x] be written" can easily be answered with "The way you want it to be written - and the way you want your readers to experience it". There doesn't seem to be a good answer that really helps you, it depends on your style, audience, ...

Comment: @Secespitus my concern comes with the influence the guide has and how it can block the self-learning of the character because i dont understand what characteristics make a guide just a guide and not a plot puller, leaving  the actual plot charge to the main character, i tried writting it but i bump into a wall where the guide ends up pulling the strings in the story too much

Comment: Such a guide would *have* an influence on the story, but your character can learn to sometimes listen and sometimes ignore the guide and thereby drive the story. You can also use the guide as a clichèe plot point by kidnapping them or your character just losing them in a crowded area. As this character will constantly be with your main character you should view it as an extension of your main character. The guide is incredibly important, but needs the help of the main character and now you have a team. Even if it's written from the perspective of one of them.

Comment: Does the character really need a guide, though? Can't he learn the world by observing and doing?

Comment: Can you give more insight of your world? This would expand (or limit) the choices of who (or what) your guide can be. Is the world that your character visiting a modern day Earth (meaning no magic except for what your character may bring with him)?

Comment: >Math is universal >Use math in your guide >Burn out the brains of unprepared people with math

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the guide a computerized teacher or companion; which can be any size convenient to your story: very small (a patch on the skin) or a robot as large as a person.

The value of using a computer is that readers will accept it as plausible if it lets the MC get into danger, or if it does not provide answers because the MC is supposed to learn something on its own, or if it does not provide answers because it just does not know.

Think of it as a child with an iPhone-like device that responds to voice commands. Such devices (IRL) have no common sense or judgment about what is safe or dangerous, what is appropriate or illegal.

Your device can be similar. An iPhone might give you good directions for getting around New York City, but it isn't going to try and stop you from wandering into parts of NYC where you can get mugged and killed.

It would be far more difficult for a living being to plausibly fill the same role. In Star Wars, R2D2 does a similar thing for Luke Skywalker. When Luke veers off to go find Yoda, R2D2 is along for the ride, and they have a one-sided conversation (beeps and whistles on R2's side) that makes it clear R2D2 is intelligent but just a robot that does as it is told and will not refuse Luke's commands, even if R2 thinks it is wrong.

(Of course you don't have to make your robot argue at all if you don't want that.)

Readers expect ***living*** beings (with adult intellect, like R2) to not just argue but at times show emotions and have concern about the harm an innocent might do to themselves, other people, or valuable property.

So a living being with the knowledge to explain the world and humans to your MC to interfere with the MC as well. It is implausible for such a living being to just watch the MC walk into high danger, or do something that might harm another person, set a building on fire, etc.

For the modern reader (IRL) the most plausible highly intelligent but non-interfering guide would be a voice from a computerized information system and instructor. Which may or may not be attached to a robotic body, depending on the needs of your plot (R2D2 takes a few actions as a 'hacker' to rescue our heroes, for example.)

Comment: You may also make the guide completely realistic, with as much and as litle, as reliable or as unreliable personality - MC has a common smartphone or a tablet, and a connection to a travel-related *forum*. Every question is answered by someone else. Questions get multiple, often conflicting answers. Depending on what forum this is, the answers may be entirely wrong or misguiding (pranks/trolling) [+](http://boards.4chan.org/trv/), or considerably in-depth and reliable [+](https://travel.stackexchange.com/). But since the responders change so frequently, readers won't establish a bond with them

Comment: @SF. +1, but you should really make that an answer. It is coherent and different enough from mine to warrant separate votes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the most powerful solution is that the presence of the guide *develops* your main character (the one you do not want 'pulled from.')

### **I believe the answer to this is through your main character's reactions to the guide, and through their relationship.**

It doesn't matter what the guide is.

**If it is books,** he can have a relationship with the books. Perhaps: He doesn't know how to read. He can only read a little. He becomes frustrated, annoyed, that this is the only way he has to learn the world. Eventually, he learns to read, and learns to love books, and this development can be taken to comical or other extremes.

**If it is a person,** he can have a very realistic relationship, pulling on all the areas that human relationships have. Power plays, attraction, repulsion, conversation, lies, truths.

**If it is a mythical creature,** he can have other reactions and relational issues. He may feel he is going crazy. He may feel others like him (formless) have followed him and are trying to influence him.

**If it is a computer intelligence,** build off of Amadeus' answer, and create his reactions and relationship to the technology. This becomes additionally interesting in the context of SF's comment, because now there can be multiple relationships occurring. And more confusion.

Your question is how to avoid detracting from the character. The answer is to make your character's **reactions and/or relationship** to the guide the **focus** of what is being learned. Incidentally, this also helps get you past issues of 'info dump,' because as he is learning, you write about his reactions to the (provided) info, not solely the info itself.